# SPSS sysmis is not sysmis

Tags: rstudio, spss

I've created a dataset with R and saved it with the "haven" package as .sav (SPSS file).

As i have real life data, it is filled with a lot of missings.
In SPSS those missings are shown like a "." and when klicking on them they are "". This is all normal.

Now there is a strange thing happening:
When i try to calculate the mean on a variable with missings, it does not work. I just get no result. Same for ANOVA.

What 's really weird is the fact that it calculates the SD for those variables.
So when calculating SD sysmis = sysmis, but not for mean?
As far as I know the mean is necesary for calculations of SD...

Anyway...If i first delete all missings [you don t see any difference, but press the delete button :) ], than everything works fine.
Unfortunately I am to lazy for pressing more than a 100 times delete on every missing.
Strg + H did not work. It says that I cannot fill in "" in numeric variables.
I also tried RECODE X (sysmis=sysmis), which does not help.
And I tried RECODE X (""=sysmis), which results in an error "not possible to test a numeric variable on strings".

I know you people have some suggestions. ;) Thanx in advance!

Here an example:

```
x1kb <- c(1:10, NA, NA, 5,6,7,8)
y1 <- rep(c(NA,777),each=8)
data1<- data.frame(x1kb, y1)

library(haven)
write_sav(as.data.frame(data1),
          paste("data1",".sav", sep=""))
```

Just open this file in SPSS and try to calculate descriptive stats.
You'll get this: No mean but SD calculated!

```
Deskriptive Statistik                   
        N       Minimum Maximum mean   SD
x1kb    16      5,00    8,00           2,34521
y1      16      777,00  777,00          ,00000
Gültige Werte (Listenweise) 16
```

After copy paste of values in and out from Excel you get the desired result:

```
Deskriptive Statistik                   
        N   Minimum Maximum Mittelwert  Standardabweichung
x1kb    14  1,00    10,00   5,7857      2,63639
y1      8   777,00  777,00  777,0000    ,00000
Gültige Werte (Listenweise) 6
```

Comment: I can't say for certain simply based on the description, but I would hazard a guess that your data is saved as string variables when you want it to be numeric.

Comment: @AndyW: thx for the hint. Unfortunately this is not the case. But you brought me on the idea just to reset the VARIABLE LEVEL to (SCALE). Unhappily it stil does not work. 
(If it would be a string, it should not be possible to calculate SD i think. )

Comment: I just found the solution. By copying all values into excel and recopying them into SPSS all missings are changed (whatever has changed i do not know, but it works). Now i get means!

Answer (score 1):

This account seems implausible.  Perhaps the file creation was not correct.  A sample of the data showing the problem along with the syntax would help.

Comment: Maybe it is a compatibility problem between the haven package and SPSS?

Comment: I installed the haven package (with R3.2) and tested the sav file creation using both NA and NaN as values.  The haven::write_sav function is simply wrong.  It is not writing the correct value for sysmis in either case.  So  I would recommend not using this package for conversion.  Since you are using SPSS Statistics anyway, I suggest that you use the STATS GET R extension command available from the SPSS Community website to convert an R data frame to a proper Statistics dataset.

Comment: p.s.  I have notified the author of the haven package about this problem.

Comment: That's nice. You may also tell the author of the haven package, that write_sav might not handle values of "Inf". If any value in the dataset is "Inf" it is saved and you can open it in SPSS. But SPSS bugs totally when trying to show the data (it shows the variables correctly).

Comment: All of those should get converted to a proper sysmis value, but currently they don't.